# Field is not writeable: Order.IsReductionOrder

Tags: trigger, order, orderitem

I am trying to update Order.IsReductionOrder to true from a trigger but getting below error.

> Field is not writeable: Order.IsReductionOrder

It looks like field is read only from [Order documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/Content/sforce_api_objects_order.htm)

[image]

Any workaround please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IsReductionOrder is writeable on create, but read-only after create. It somewhat makes sense from a business process perspective, an order either is a reduction order or it's not, it shouldn't ever start as a normal order and then become a reduction order.